# ASP.NET double Range() does not accept decimal numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, range, data-annotations

I'm new in the ASP.NET world and started with following an MVA ASP.NET course. During the course video I noticed some misbehaviour in my application, but the application in the video was working ok. So, I have a class which has the following definition for member Price:

```
   [Required]
   [Range(0.00,999.99)]
   public double Price { get; set; }
```

Seems simple, but when I browse into the form and try to enter price, only numbers without decimal point are accepted. Even zero decimals are not allowed:

The value '12.00' is not valid for Price.

No matter if I enter the number with decimal point or with decimal comma, as we use comma as separator here in Finland. Only numbers without decimal part are allowed, like 15 or 12.

What I'm doing wrong? All the files are similar to the course files. Does this relate to the Finnish decimal comma?

The field is decribed like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Price" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
   [Range(typeof(decimal), 0.00,999.99)]
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
```